# This is not a carol

Tags: knowledge

> Originally the word of a king,
>   this is a rather different thing:
>   
>   Named by slaughter of the innocent dead,
>   where one should literally only make bread,
>   he is sent on a ride, with friends at his side
>   like funny and white, they go down a slide.
>   
>   Rebellious in secret they search for the link,
>   against negative ice and electricity blink,
>   against woodcutters's hum and white streaked fire,
>   protagonists wither, cheated victors lay dire.
>   
>   Still the main pair prevails, disappears in the rubble.
>   Brute force is faked to end all this trouble,
>   but the real end comes, when the truth they can tell,
>   and the butcher redeemed sends the demon to hell.

What is described here?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just a quick one that came to mind. Hope it's not too boring for you.

Comment: I haven't any idea what this is, but it sounds very familiar.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie: I thought they would not. It's in rhyme form, but that's obvious. You don't need to rhyme to solve. And it's not really a riddle either, just a description. Not much depth here. Either you know it, or you don't

Comment: @generalcrispy: If this sounds very familiar, than maybe you have it somewhere deep in memory. The description is not very cryptic and there is not much to dedcue. If you know it, it should ring a bell loud enough. Can't see your age, though. If you're too young, you probably don't know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is...

> the plot of 'The Running Man' from 1987 starring Arnold Schwarzenegger. Extremely loosely based on a Stephen **King** novel, it's about Ben Richards **wrongly accused of a massacre** in **Baker**sfield and dubbed a **Butcher** who's then sent into a deadly gameshow **down a shoot** alongside fellow competitors **Laughlin and Weiss**. They fight game champs like **Subzero**, **Buzzsaw** and **Dynamo** (who electrifies people) while looking for a satellite **uplink**. In the end, the two protagonists survive and **air the truth** about the game, and the butcher **blows Damon (the host) up.** *[Plus, it's **not the Carol** Reed 1963 movie 'The Running Man'.]*

Comment: Absolutely! - And perfectly summarized, every last detail in there.